# The javascript project doesn't work properly when run on a server from eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I have a maven web project which includes some javascript code. It works fine when I deploy the war to a tomcat server. But doesn't work properly when I run it from eclipse as it failed to deploy some files or directories.

Comment: I'd suggest elaborating on "doesn't work properly", or someone will close this out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for missed scripts/dirs is I didn't republish the project.